# embed a WinForms app in a web page?

Tags: .net, winforms

Is there a way to embed a WinForms app in a web page (assuming the browser is running on a machine with .NET)?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: No... I want the WinForms app to live inside a web page... not just be launched / installed from the web.

Comment: That's not possible. You could do it with ActiveX.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment above, you might want to convert to Silverlight-

Answer (score 0):

You can embed winforms *controls* in a page, but it only works on IE.

Comment: Do you have any more info on that (link, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an ActiveX control in .Net:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dsandor/ActiveXInNet11102005040748AM/ActiveXInNet.aspx

I'm definitely not saying you *should*, but you *can*.